# jQuery AJAX autorefresh on error

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, the window.setTimeout(update, 5000); does not work. It does not retry the function after 5 seconds upon error.

```
function powercyclestatus() {
    $("#status").html("<div align='center'><img src='modules/servers/flosoftdedicated/images/ajax/loading-warning.gif' border='0' alt='' /><br />Requesting Powercycle Status.</div>"); 
  $('#status').addClass('warning');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'clientarea.php',
    data: 'action=productdetails&id=' + $('#serverid').val() + '&modop=custom&a=powercyclestatus',
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#powercycleresult").html(data);
      $("#status").html("<div align='center'><img src='modules/servers/flosoftdedicated/images/ajax/success.png' border='0' alt='' /><br />Powercycle complete.</div>"); 
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $("#status").html(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
      $("#powercycleresult").html();
      window.setTimeout(update, 5000);
    }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script tries to call the function `update` after 5 seconds. Bit their is no update-function.

I think you want to retry the powercyclestatus-function. So sou need

```
window.setTimeout(powercyclestatus, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you attemping to retry? You don't have an "update" function provided in your code, are you attempting to run the entire powercyclestatus() function again? In which case:

```
window.setTimeout(powercyclestatus, 5000);
```

Comment: ah, same comment was added while I was posting. You might want to just recall the ajax portion of the powercyclestatus function, in which case you could wrap that in a function as well, and call just that part again.